# Can I do a train-test split by taking alternate indexes of a time series?

Tags: time-series

I have two time series of the position (x- and y-coordinates) of a moving rat - these are the labels. The features are recordings of brain activities (~48 channels). I plan to train a LSTM using these as features and labels. The issue is that the rat is more active in the first half of the session than the second half, so splitting it by the usual 80%/40% may not generate representative training labels (or test labels), because the level of activity is much lower in the second half than first half.

I am wondering if I can do a 50/50 train-test split by just taking alternate sample points and then concatenating them, like follow (each being an individual measurement, not window):
[Train test split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEq5n.png)
I understand that with this the train and test samples become highly correlated, but that isn't a requirement for train and test to not be correlated, right? This preserves the temporal order, and effectively is akin to 'downsampling' the time series anyway.

I don't see this being done, so I'm just wondering what might be the issue here.